# How to make HTML buttons responsive

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for a basic website I'm making. I'm doing it for a school project.

```css
.html-button {
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 21px;
  background: #42A5F6;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.html-button:hover {
  background: #0090FF;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.css-button {
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 55.3%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 21px;
  background: #42A5F6;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.css-button:hover {
  background: #0090FF;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="html-button" role="button">VIEW HTML</button>
<button class="css-button" role="button">VIEW CSS</button>
```

That is not my entire code, but that's the main part that I'm focusing on here. This will display 2 separate buttons (decorated with CSS), on my screen, they are the perfect length apart, however currently, when I make my browser smaller, the buttons push closer together as it gets smaller, how might I prevent this?

Comment: Your css is a mass, i think you can do this mach more clean and clear. And you can make your buttons 45% width and 2.5% margin from left and right, it's probably solve your problem.

Comment: How so? Sorry, I'm new to CSS & I'm only 9. :P

Comment: I would suggest you to use Bootstrap, it's the easiest way to make your website responsive, it contains everything you need. Go to http://getbootstrap.com and try it.

Comment: Try to use one class for your two buttons for start.

Comment: And different ids?

Comment: @Imaginaroom I usually encourage people to use toolkits, but not for school. If I was a teacher asking him to prove his CSS knowledge from root level, I'd probably ask for no toolkit usage (maybe for higher-level projects)

Comment: Katana314, how else would I be able to get it to be responsive?

Comment: @Katana314 You have a great point there :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have positioned the buttons absolutely. There is a much cleaner way to do this with much less code. I would suggest putting them both in a div and positioning that where you want it instead, like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button" role="button">VIEW HTML</button>
  <button class="button" role="button">VIEW CSS</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
}
.button {
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 21px;
  background: #42A5F6;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: none;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #0090FF;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Yes, they were both in a div but like an idiot I didn't show it.

Comment: How would you add more spaces between the buttons? I wanted to add around 3.

Comment: If you want to add more space between the buttons you can include a right margin on them like this: `margin-right: 10px;` in the `.button` class.

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation would be to not use absolute position on the buttons, rather absolutely position their container, and then position the buttons relative to that.

Absolute positioning (from W3Schools):

> if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

This basically says that it's calculating your `left` and `top` percentages against the width of the browser window, and when your browser window size changes, it recalculates accordingly and pushes the buttons closer together.

Instead, if you want 2 buttons side by side in the center of the screen, try something like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/5btchz9j/

Also, kudos for learning this stuff so early, I certainly wasn't building websites at 9 :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help & positive comment. :-)